# trouble using AFOAuth2manager to generate HTTPSOauthToken

Tags: ios, oauth, woocommerce, afoauth2client

I'm building an iOS app where costumers can login (with the same website username and password) into the app and purchase items from the app. The rest api for woo commerce says to use HTTP Basic Auth by providing the API Consumer Key as the username and the API Consumer Secret as the password. I've been researching a lot and I'm getting nowhere really. Right now I im trying AFOAuth2manager and here is my code i have so far and not working

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
AFOAuth2Manager *oAuthManager = [[AFOAuth2Manager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL
                                                                clientID: keyClientID
                                                                  secret:keyClientSecret];

[oAuthManager authenticateUsingOAuthWithURLString:@"/oauth/token"
                                         username:myUserName
                                         password:myPassword
                                            scope:@"email"
                                          success:^(AFOAuthCredential *credential) {
                                              NSLog(@"Token: %@",credential.accessToken);
                                          } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                              NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                          }];


//Authorizing requests
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

[manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:keyClientID password:keyClientSecret];

[manager GET:@"/path/to/protected/resource"
  parameters:nil
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"Succes: %@", responseObject);
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
     }];

//storing credentials
AFOAuthCredential *credential = [[AFOAuthCredential alloc] init];

[AFOAuthCredential storeCredential: credential withIdentifier:serviceProviderIdentifier];

//retrieving credentials
AFOAuthCredential *storedCredential = [AFOAuthCredential retrieveCredentialWithIdentifier:serviceProviderIdentifier];
NSLog(@"%@", storedCredential);
```

I get this error: NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: not found (404), along with a long list of numbers.
Anyways Im looking for some guide over all about the process, I need to have the user login in my app, my app confirms that the user has an account with the website,user can purchase items on my app and I post the orders to the website for processing. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
AFOAuth2Manager *oAuthManager = [[AFOAuth2Manager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL
                                                                clientID: keyClientID
                                                                  secret:keyClientSecret];

[oAuthManager authenticateUsingOAuthWithURLString:@"/oauth/token"
                                         username:myUserName
                                         password:myPassword
                                            scope:@"email"
                                          success:^(AFOAuthCredential *credential) {
                                              NSLog(@"Token: %@",credential.accessToken);

//Authorizing requests
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

[manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithCredential:authCredential];

[manager GET:@"/path/to/protected/resource"
  parameters:nil
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"Succes: %@", responseObject);
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
     }];

                                          } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                              NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                          }];
```

...for testing the mechanism!